# Adding extraEnv to helm chart via terraform and terragrunt

Tags: apache-spark, dynamic, terraform, kubernetes-helm, environment

I need to set additional variables in my value.yaml (link to jaeger https://github.com/jaegertracing/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jaeger/values.yaml#L495) helm chart via terraform + terragrunt. In values.yaml, the code looks like this:

```
spark:
  extraEnv: []
```

It is necessary that it be like this:

```
spark:
  extraEnv:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
```

Terraform uses this dynamic block:

```
dynamic "set" {
  for_each = var.extraEnv
  content {
    name = "spark.extraEnv [${set.key}]"
    value = set.value
  }
}
```

The variable is defined like this:

```
variable "extraEnv" {
  type = map
}
```

From terragrunt I pass the value of the variable:

```
extraEnv = {
  "JAVA_OPTS" = "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: failed parsing key "spark.extraEnv [JAVA_OPTS]" with value -Xms4g -Xmx4g, error parsing index: strconv.Atoi: parsing "JAVA_OPTS": invalid syntax

  on main.tf line 16, in resource "helm_release" "jaeger":
  16: resource "helm_release" "jaeger" {
```

Tell me how to use the dynamic block correctly in this case. I suppose that in this case you need to use a list of maps, but I do not understand how to use this in a dynamic block.

**UPD:**
I solved my problem in a different way.

In values, defined the list 'spark.extraEnv' using yamlencode.

```
values = [
    "${file("${path.module}/values.yaml")}",
    yamlencode({
      spark = {
        extraEnv = var.spark_extraEnv
      }
    })
]
```

in variables.tf

```
variable "spark_extraEnv" {
  type = list(object({
    name  = string
    value = string
  }))
}
```

And in terragrunt passed the following variable value:

```
spark_extraEnv   = [
    {
      name  = "JAVA_OPTS"
      value = "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I landed here while I was looking for setting extraEnv for a different chart. Finally figured answer for the above question as well:

```
  set {
    name  = "extraEnv[0].name"
    value = "JAVA_OPTS"
  }

  set {
    name  = "extraEnv[0].value"
    value = "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
  }
```

Comment: thank you for this.  I think this is the 6th different syntax I have tried.  Why in the world don't the helm provider docs have examples of this?

Comment: Helm is an open-source project and it's up to folks like us to make it better by submitting a PR/MR with the suggested changes to the docs :)